# Capybara cannot click_button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Updated:

"The RackTest driver can't click on buttons which aren't within a form." by jnicklas

ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-capybara/ECc4U_dux08

Origin:

I've struggled with this problem for hours but cannot understand why. Could you please help me?

index.html.haml

```
.welcome.ac
    %h1.brand.text-info GroupMeal
        %h2.tagline
        The simplest way of scheduling meals with your groups and friends
    %p
        - if !current_user
            %button#fblogin.btn.btn-info.btn-large Login with Facebook
        - else
            %a.btn.btn-info.btn-large{:href => '/signout'} Sign out\
```

authentications_spec.rb

```
describe "page" do
  before do
    visit root_path
  end
  it { should have_button('Login with Facebook') } # 1. This case is passed
  describe "with valid information" do
    before do
      click_button('Login with Facebook') # 2. But this line is broken
    end
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: '/signout') } 
  end
end
```

Case 1: verify that "Login with Facebook" button is existed --> passed.
Case 2: click_button --> failed and receive below error.

```
Failure/Error: click_button('Login with Facebook')
NoMethodError:
    undefined method `node_name' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand why the button is existed but it cannot be clicked.

Comment: Would you be able to post the full stack trace when you run the spec with --trace?

Answer (score 0):

Each **describe** block creates a new scope, so RSpec is no longer on the root page for your app in the second one. You either have to instruct RSPec to visit the root again or change your first **before** block to a **before(:each)** block so it runs before each test.

RSpec sets up each **describe** block this way because, when writing tests, each test should be able to be run on its own--the order of the tests shouldn't matter, so having one test set up conditions for another is a bad idea.

If I were you, I would write this as follows, presuming all the tests you're placing in the **describe "page"** block are supposed to test features on the root page (if so, I would change "page" to "root page" so it's clear what's being tested):

```
describe 'root page' do
  before(:each) do
    visit '/'
  end

  # Calling subject will allow you to keep using "it" 
  # in case you want to test other aspects of the root 
  # page here. It's worth noting that click_button
  # will tell you if it can't find the button you're
  # asking for, so you don't really need the next two
  # lines as things currently stand.
  subject { page }

  it { should have_button('Login with Facebook') }

  describe 'signing in with valid information' do
    specify do
      click_button('Login with Facebook')
      page.should have_link('Sign out', href: '/signout' )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ````before do```` is the same as ````before(:each)```` actually.

Comment: According to /The RSpec Book/:

"To group examples by initial state, or context, RSpec provides a `before()` method that can run either one time before `:all` the examples in an example group or once before `:each` of the examples. In general, it’s better to use `before(:each)` because that re-creates the context before each example and keeps state from leaking from example to example."

If I write a test like the one above and use `before do`, the tests don't pass, also.

Comment: That is good advice. My point was that before do is an alias for before(:each), it is not an alias for before(:all).